# Load number of Images at a Time

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have about 500 static images as `EmbeddedResource`. Right now I show the images with the help of a slider. So when the slider value changes, I load the corresponding image.

```
        private void pageSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue / StepValue);

            pageSlider.Value = newStep * StepValue;
            pageNumber.Text = pageSlider.Value.ToString();
            pageImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("SApp.Images.SPages.page" + pageSlider.Value.ToString() + ".jpg",typeof(AboutPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        }
```

Now, as the slide is not that much user friendly to iterate thru 500 images (total image size 40 MB), what is the right way to load the images.
I thought to load it in `Carousal control`, but the current layout is `TabbedPage`, so I cannot do this.
Other option is to load all the images to `ListView`, but will it make issue with memory ? Or `ListView` with `Paging` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a `CollectionView` and [Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally). Or use it [pull to refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#pull-to-refresh) capability by wrapping it inside a `RefreshView`, you will be able to load your images async.

**Edit**

From [source:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)

> CollectionView is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView.

For information, you can use Pull to Refresh ([Xamarin.Forms RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)) in both `ListView` or `CollectionView`.

2. Beside that, for a faster image loading and smoother scrolling on **Android only**, you can use [glidex.forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/glidex.forms/) package, [Official repo/docs](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex).

Comment: Yes. This is it. I have just browsed through the documentation and it supports more features like ```Context menu, Pull to refresh, Load data incrementally```,

Answer (score 2):

> I thought to load it in Carousal control, but the current layout is TabbedPage, so I cannot do this. Other option is to load all the images to ListView, but will it make issue with memory ? Or ListView with Paging ?

Maybe you can try to use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) to display image in ListView, or just update image source when silder value update.

There are some features:

1. Configurable disk and memory caching
2. Multiple image views using the same image source (url, path, resource) will use only one bitmap which is cached in memory (less memory usage)
3. Error and loading placeholders support
4. Images can be automatically downsampled to specified size (less memory usage)

Comment: How about ```CollectionView``` as Cfun suggested.

Comment: @Rauf I suggest you use ListView to do, because ListView has **ListViewCachingStrategy** property, The **RecycleElement** caching strategy specifies that the ListView will attempt to minimize its memory footprint and execution speed by recycling list cells.

Comment: [CollectionView automatically uses the virtualization provided by the underlying native controls.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)